# get OnClick() from programmatically added buttons?

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

i have added some button in a layout:

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.KeysList);
    keys=db.getKeys(console);

    my_button=new Button[keys.size()];
    for (bt=0;bt<keys.size();bt++){
           my_button[bt]=new Button(this);
           my_button[bt].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
           my_button[bt].setText(keys.get(bt));
           my_button[bt].setId(bt);
           row.addView(my_button[bt]);
           my_button[bt].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (my_button[bt].getId() == ((Button) v).getId()){
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), keys.get(bt), 0).show();
                  }
              }
           });
        }
```

I want to know which button is clicked and how to get text of the clicked button?
And I think using bt here dose not seem to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is running. I hope it help you :)

```
    final ArrayList<String> Keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        Keys.add("Keys is : " + String.valueOf(i));
    }

    LinearLayout Row = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.KeysList);

    final Button[] my_button = new Button[Keys.size()];

    for (int bt = 0; bt < Keys.size(); bt ++){
        final int Index = bt;

        my_button[Index] = new Button(this);
        my_button[Index].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        my_button[Index].setText(Keys.get(Index));
        my_button[Index].setId(Index);

        my_button[bt].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (my_button[Index].getId() == ((Button) v).getId()){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Keys.get(Index), 0).show();
                }
            }
        });

        Row.addView(my_button[Index]);
    }
```

ExampleProject id : [Your project](http://www.anadoluprogramlama.com/TestProject.rar)

Comment: Works! The key is:
final int Index = bt;

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`View#setTag`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) to set some arbitrary data you'd like associate with the Button. Then you can just instantiate only one `OnClickListener` that then uses `getTag` and acts on that data in whatever way you need.

Comment: Thanks! This great answer should be marked as solution, because it is much cleaner and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have your Activity listen to all button clicks and then you just filter respective to the ID. You should not get the text of the button and use that at all. You should use your own type of identifier, ideally the idea should be enough. Or perhaps you use setTag as @qberticus described.

Answer (score 0):

Consider This example :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{

LinearLayout linearLayout;
Button [] button;
View.OnClickListener listener;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_lay);
    String[] array={"U123","U124","U125"};
    int length=array.length;
    System.out.println("11111111111111111111111111");
    button=new Button[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        button[i]=new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button[i].setId(i);
        button[i].setText("User" + i);
        button[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        linearLayout.addView(button[i]);
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    view.getId();
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(view.getId());
    button.setText("Changed");
}
}
```

This works fine :)